# javascript - generate and print the total average final grade of all students

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I'm trying to generate and print the total average final grade of all students with the weighting: assignment=40%, tutorial=10%, exam=50%.I keep running into different errors saying I'm missing a bracket or something and I also feel like I'm not doing it right. I was wondering if someone could push me in the right direction?

```js
let students = [{
      fname: "Jane",
      lname: "Brazier",
      snum: "100366942",
      agrade: 67.59127376966494,
      tgrade: 64.86530868914188,
      egrade: 70.52944558104066
    }, {
      fname: "Ricardo",
      lname: "Allen",
      snum: "100345641",
      agrade: 65.80370345301014,
      tgrade: 75.40211705841241,
      egrade: 55.39348896202821
    }, {
      fname: "Mary",
      lname: "Hernandez",
      snum: "100221207",
      agrade: 71.20761408935981,
      tgrade: 71.37529197926764,
      egrade: 75.82038980457698
    }, {
      fname: "James",
      lname: "Johnson",
      snum: "100200842",
      agrade: 72.5791318299902,
      tgrade: 81.65883679807183,
      egrade: 85.19664228946989
    }, {
      fname: "Gene",
      lname: "Jeanlouis",
      snum: "100341666",
      agrade: 74.16481515505846,
      tgrade: 68.20592386917109,
      egrade: 78.25975050135006
    }];


    var examAverage = students.reduce(function (accumulator, student) {
     return accumulator + student.egrade;
    }, 0);

    var assignmentAverage = students.reduce(function (accumulator, student) {
     return accumulator + student.agrade;
    }, 0);

    var tutorialAverage = students.reduce(function (accumulator, student) {
     return accumulator + student.tgrade;
    }, 0);

    var totalAverage = ((examAverage*0.5)+(assignmentAverage*0.4)+(tutorialAverage*0.1));
    console.log(totalAverage);
```

Update: so it currently prints out 359 which is obviously too high. I'm not sure why it's doing that. It should print out an average within 0-100

Comment: Change , 0}; to , 0); you are starting parenthesis '(' but closing braces '}'

Comment: Use runnable snippets next time you push a question on JS. Then, please, syntax errors are on you... You must master the basics before posting.

Comment: I changed it to  0); but now it says 'unexpected token )'

Comment: @Grayish check your script man... Close your brackets/parenthesis, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't calculate the average of `egrade, agrade and tgrade`. You have to find out the average after calculating the sum by divining the length of students array

Also, I suggest you not to use the multiple `.reduce()`. By a single iteration (`.reduce`) you can calculate the sum easily.

```
var sum = students.reduce(function (acc, cur) {
    acc.egrade += cur.egrade;
    acc.agrade += cur.agrade;
    acc.tgrade += cur.tgrade;
    return acc;
}, {egrade: 0, agrade: 0, tgrade: 0});

var totalAverage = (sum.egrade / students.length) * 0.5 + (sum.agrade / students.length) * 0.4 + (sum.tgrade / students.length) * 0.1;
console.log(totalAverage);
```

Answer (score 0):

You were missing `)` to close your function's. It's working like a charm now, check below:

```js
var students = [{
  fname: "Jane",
  lname: "Brazier",
  snum: "100366942",
  agrade: 67.59127376966494,
  tgrade: 64.86530868914188,
  egrade: 70.52944558104066
}, {
  fname: "Ricardo",
  lname: "Allen",
  snum: "100345641",
  agrade: 65.80370345301014,
  tgrade: 75.40211705841241,
  egrade: 55.39348896202821
}, {
  fname: "Mary",
  lname: "Hernandez",
  snum: "100221207",
  agrade: 71.20761408935981,
  tgrade: 71.37529197926764,
  egrade: 75.82038980457698
}, {
  fname: "James",
  lname: "Johnson",
  snum: "100200842",
  agrade: 72.5791318299902,
  tgrade: 81.65883679807183,
  egrade: 85.19664228946989
}, {
  fname: "Gene",
  lname: "Jeanlouis",
  snum: "100341666",
  agrade: 74.16481515505846,
  tgrade: 68.20592386917109,
  egrade: 78.25975050135006
}];


var examAverage = students.reduce(function (accumulator, student) {
    return accumulator + student.egrade;
}, 0);

var assignmentAverage = students.reduce(function (accumulator, student) {
    return accumulator + student.agrade;
}, 0);

var tutorialAverage = students.reduce(function (accumulator, student) {
    return accumulator + student.tgrade;
}, 0);

var totalAverage = ((examAverage*0.5)+(assignmentAverage*0.4)+(tutorialAverage*0.1));

console.log(totalAverage);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use an abstact approach by taking some helper arrays, one for the wanted keys and for the weights.

```js
let students = [{ fname: "Jane", lname: "Brazier", snum: "100366942", agrade: 67.59127376966494, tgrade: 64.86530868914188, egrade: 70.52944558104066 }, { fname: "Ricardo", lname: "Allen", snum: "100345641", agrade: 65.80370345301014, tgrade: 75.40211705841241, egrade: 55.39348896202821 }, { fname: "Mary", lname: "Hernandez", snum: "100221207", agrade: 71.20761408935981, tgrade: 71.37529197926764, egrade: 75.82038980457698 }, { fname: "James", lname: "Johnson", snum: "100200842", agrade: 72.5791318299902, tgrade: 81.65883679807183, egrade: 85.19664228946989 }, { fname: "Gene", lname: "Jeanlouis", snum: "100341666", agrade: 74.16481515505846, tgrade: 68.20592386917109, egrade: 78.25975050135006 }],
    keys = ['agrade', 'tgrade', 'egrade'],
    weights = [0.4, 0.1, 0.5],
    sums = students.reduce(function (accumulator, student) {
        keys.forEach(function (key) {
            accumulator[key] = (accumulator[key] || 0) + student[key];
        });
        return accumulator;
    }, {}),
    totalAverage = weights.reduce(function (sum, weight, index) {
         return sum + sums[keys[index]] / students.length * weight;
    }, 0);

console.log(totalAverage);
```